# What's the best way to write e-mail addresses?

Tags: symbols, addresses

When trying to write an e-mail address, there are always problems with the @ sign.

Solutions I've seen suggested are using some verbatim environment (more difficult in footnotes) and using a math-mode @.

What is *the* correct way to do this?

Comment: Additionally you can redefine the arrobase (@) to be a different font and/or size. Thats why I do for my resume to make it really pop!

Comment: egreg's answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128515/15874) is the way to go.

Comment: If you dont need an actual link, use the 'url' package and the \url{} command.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Another thing one can to with the [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/hyperref.html) package is to use the `href` command

```
\href{mailto:me@example.com}{me@example.com}
```

which has the advantage that when clicked-on in an electronic document, it will (ideally) call up the mailer and cue up the e-mail address.

Comment: I often define an `\email` command that expands to your `\href`, automatically prepending the `mailto:` part.

Comment: Good idea. One small caveat is that <code>\email</code> is already defined in certain document classes (for example <code>amsart</code>).

Comment: how do I do it in TexWorks ? it does not have hyperef, right ? How do I install hyperef in TexWorks ?

Comment: @user25957: I am not familiar with TexWorks, do [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19390/how-do-you-download-packages-for-texworks-on-windows-7) or other questions in the [tag:texworks] tag help? If not try asking a new question about it.

Comment: @user25957 TeXWorks is an editor. It doesn't matter if you use TeXWorks, TeXShop, TeXMaker, TeXNicCenter, TeXLipse, Notepad, Emacs, Gedit, or whatever. It will always invoke the TeX distribution on your computer (TeX Live or possibly MiKTeX on Windows) which will _most probably_ include `hyperref`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, but I have always been wondering if there is a way to create something like "click and copy to clipboard". Because clicking on a `\href` link always redirects me to an email client, which I do not use! So it makes more sense for me if I can just click on the email address and it is copied to my clipboard! Is it even possible in `LaTeX`? Thanks!

Comment: For the lazy, @DamienPollet meant: use `\newcommand{\email}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}` somewhere in your preamble, that'll do just fine.

Comment: sorry, and thanks ;-)

Answer (score 69):

You can also combine the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`url`](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) approaches to get a working link that is formatted like an URL:

```
\href{mailto:me@example.com}{\nolinkurl{me@example.com}}
```

Answer (score 27):

Just to add to Willie's good answer, in terms of the formatting (as the OP seems to be getting at) there isn't a "correct" way. Use `\textsf` or `\texttt` or whatever looks good for your particular document and use case and font choice. Also try the `randtext` package to attempt to obfuscate the email address inside the PDF to make it less susceptible to spammers (but note that — I think — it doesn't play nice with hyperref's `\href`).

If you want to "special-case" the @ sign without adding markup to your text, you could write something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
    \catcode`\_=11\relax
    \newcommand\email[1]{\_email #1\q_nil}
    \def\_email#1@#2\q_nil{%
      \href{mailto:#1@#2}{{\emailfont #1\emailampersat #2}}
    }
    \newcommand\emailfont{\sffamily}
    \newcommand\emailampersat{{\color{red}\small@}}
    \catcode`\_=8\relax    
\begin{document}
\email{foobar@gmail.com}
\end{document}
```

where you get the proper hyperlinking of the email address and you can customise the look of the email by changing `\emailfont` and the look of the ampersat (or arrobase, or @) by changing `\emailampersat`.

Comment: Yeah.. mentioning `randtext` was exactly what I needed. Just curious... does your command still produce a working hyperlink if I wrap a `randtext{}` around it? I suppose not...

Answer (score 18):

You can define `\at` command in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\at}{\makeatletter @\makeatother}
```

and then use it as follows within the document:

```
myemail\at gmail.com
```

Comment: The catcode of `@` in `\at` is the catcode that was set for `@` at the *time of the definition*. If the catcode of `@` should be "letter", then it is defined via `\makeatletter\newcommand*{\at}{@}\makeatother`. However, the catcode "letter" or "other" does not matter here, thus `\newcommand*{\at}{@}` would be enough or just using `@`.

Comment: I can read this comment above twenty times and still be confused. Sounds like Alan Greenspan quote: `I know that you think you know what I said. But I'm not sure whether you understood that what you heard is what I meant.`

Comment: haha it's usual feeling when trying to read Tex manuals ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Very simple solution from [here](http://computingfunnyfacts.blogspot.com/2009/05/adding-at-symbol-to-latex.html):

`\texttt{john@gmail.com}`

Comment: The curly grouping braces around `@` are not needed.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't like how the at-symbol of the default font looks (I don't), you may borrow it from the Times font, like so: `youraddres{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont @}example.com`

Answer (score 4):

For the `@` character I prefer the `\MVAt` command from the `marvosym` package, since the cmss `@` looks so different from other fonts I'm used to. For the full address I use the `hyperref` formatting suggested by Willie.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there is a unique correct way to handle this. As another answer says, you can use hyperref. But, the [url](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/url.html) package can also be used to render email addresses:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\url{me@example.com}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't want to use `\url` because it will attempt to create a hyperlink to an actual URL with the email address you supply. See Caramdir's answer for a better solution.

Comment: @WillRobertson: You sure about that? Note that this was `\url` from the url package, not from hyperref.

Comment: Oops; I meant only if you load hyperref as well -- it will transparently replace `\url` with the hyperlinked one. The point is that `\url` is not semantically designed for email addresses.

Comment: Logical markup can be defined with package `url` via `\DeclareUrlCommand\email{}` and used as `\email{me@example.com}`.

Comment: Would this logical markup works if both the url and hyperref packages are loaded, @HeikoOberdiek ?

Comment: @DrBeco The `url` package is loaded by `hyperref` and the `\DeclareUrlCommand` works. But the result is not a link.

Answer (score 3):

I defined a command, to avoid the redundancy of Willie Wong's and Caramdir's answers, and to allow protocols other than `mailto`:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\thelink}{\@empty}
\newcommand{\link}[2]{%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{:}{\renewcommand\thelink{#1}}{\renewcommand\thelink{#1:#2}}%
  \href{\thelink}{\texttt{#2}}%
}
```

There's a long form, where the URL is different than the text, and the short form, where the protocol is catenated with the text to make up the URL:

```
Phone: \link{tel:1234567890}{+1 234-567-890} \\
E-mail: \link{mailto}{foo@bar.spam}
```

Produces this result:

[image: latex rendered output]

I use `\texttt` instead of `\nolinkurl`, because the latter removed spaces from the supplied text.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that you can try:

(with the hyperref package):

> \url{email address}

or more simply (for monospace font):

> \texttt{email address}

Comment: You don't want to use `\url` because it will attempt to create a hyperlink to an actual URL with the email address you supply. See Caramdir's answer for a better solution.