# How do you download packages for TeXworks on Windows 7?

Tags: packages, installing, texworks

I am using TeXworks on Windows 7 and I want to use the `algorithmic` package. However, when I try to include it it just says I need to download that package, but I can't figure out how to download it (TeXworks asks if you want to download it automatically, but that doesn't seem to work, because nothing visible happens)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use MiKTeX, open the MiKTeX Package Manager aka mpm and choose to install the [algorithms package](http://miktex.org/packages/algorithms). It contains the algorithmic package.

If you use TeX Live, do the same with the TeX Live Manager aka tlmgr.

Each of these programs should be available in the Windows start menu if the corresponding TeX distribution has been installed.

Comment: I might need your help. I'm downloading Lilypond because I read that I can use it to include musical examples in TeX documents.