# Where to find texworks editor

Tags: texworks

Following this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19390/how-do-you-download-packages-for-texworks-on-windows-7), I have installed algorithm package in order to use texworks. However, as you can see in the picture below, there is no sign of that.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: You installed the algorithm package in order to use texworks? There is something messed up. texworks is an editor that was developed for typing in LaTeX stuff. the algorithm package is a latex package. Completely different and unrelated things.

Comment: `algorithms: A suite of tools for typesetting algorithms in pseudo-code.` So that should be an editor

Comment: No, It is not. Sorry

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: I am not sure. Install the algorithms package (set the tick and click install), open texworks (start menu), read the documentation of the algorithms package.

Comment: OK. The package is `collection-texworks` with the description "TeXworks editor; TL includes only the Windows binary"

Comment: texworks and any particular package such as `algorithm` or `array` or `longtable` are completely unrelated. texworks is an editor that you can use to write tex files, latex packages are input by latex to define the typesetting in a document.

Comment: In case you were looking to install the TeXworks editor, with which you can write and edit LaTeX documents: installation packages can be found [here](http://www.tug.org/texworks/#Getting_TeXworks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install TeX Live 2018 on Windows it should  have installed a copy of TeXworks by default. This should have been made accessible via the installation script.

However if for any reason you did not follow the usual route a shortcut may not be obvious. TeX Live includes in addition to the main tlmgr-gui.exe an additional GUI **tlaunch.exe** (which includes some related configuration) where you can set the default editor as in this image. AVOID Notepad it will not understand the TeX commands.

[image]

Depending on how a custom install was configured you may already have a copy of **texworks.exe** in the relevant binary folder. To check you can search for tlmgr-gui and check within that folder.
If you can not find it then to install it using the manager see this screen.

[image]

Comment: I chose a custom installation. So, with my choices, the TeXwork hadn't been installed.

Comment: Even a "Custom" install may include TeXworks see if there is a TeXworks.exe in the same bin folder