# apa bibliography style gives undefined control sequence \visibility{cite}

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style, undefined, apa7

This is the first time I am using Biblatex, biber or APA.

The following works:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\title{test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\textcite{Boaler:2016}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The following does not work:

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\title{test}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\textcite{Boaler:2016}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The first error message I get is

```
 ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument>  \visibility 
                        {cite} \keypart { \namepart [use=true]{prefix} \name...
l.262 }
```

I am using TeXworks on Microsoft, uncertain about versions of stuff but I can probably find out how to check those that are likely to be the issue of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `biblatex` package is not the latest one. That command (`\visibility{cite}`) was introduced in version 3.18. You should be able to simply update the `biblatex` package in TeXLive or MikTeX. You should also make sure you are using the latest `biber` version (2.18) as it's paired with the `biblatex` version.

Comment: Thanks, updating packages now as per instructions here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19390/how-do-you-download-packages-for-texworks-on-windows-7