# Typesetting email address

Tags: typography, addresses

I have found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/663/15874) by Will Robertson on how to typeset an email address:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}

\catcode`\_=11\relax
\newcommand\email[1]{\_email #1\q_nil}
\def\_email#1@#2\q_nil{%
  \href{mailto:#1@#2}{{\emailfont #1\emailampersat #2}}
}
\newcommand\emailfont{\sffamily}
\newcommand\emailampersat{{\color{red}\small@}}
catcode`\_=8\relax    

\begin{document}
\email{foobar@gmail.com}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that it doesn't work if there is an underscore in the address. How do I add such a feature?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The easiest way is to detokenize the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
    \catcode`\_=11\relax
    \newcommand\email[1]{\_email #1\q_nil}
    \def\_email#1@#2\q_nil{%
      \href{mailto:#1@#2}
        {{\emailfont\detokenize{#1}\emailampersat\detokenize{#2}}}%
    }
    \newcommand\emailfont{\sffamily}
    \newcommand\emailampersat{{\color{red}\small@}}
    \catcode`\_=8\relax   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\email{foo_bar@gmail.com}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27):

You can use [`url`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUrlCommand\email{\urlstyle{rm}}

\begin{document}
\email{foo_bar@gmail.com}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

An [`expl3`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3) implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color,xparse,l3regex,hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\email}{m}
 {
  \svend_email:n { #1 }
 }
\tl_new:N \l_svend_email_tl
\seq_new:N \l_svend_email_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \svend_email:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_svend_email_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \cD. } { \c{textunderscore} } \l_svend_email_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_svend_email_seq { @ } \l_svend_email_tl
  \href{ mailto:#1 }{ \emailfont \seq_use:Nn \l_svend_email_seq { \emailat } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\emailfont{\sffamily}
\newcommand\emailat{{\color{red}\small @}}

\begin{document}
\email{foobar@gmail.com}
\email{foo_bar@gmail.com}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What it the difference between this and Will's approach?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg This will work also if the address has no `@`. It also improves on Joseph's as it doesn't force usage of the T1 encoding.