# How I can type an underscore character (_) that's part of an email address?

Tags: hyperref, urls, email

I am typing a scientific article using latex nowadays. My e-mail address is `ufukkaya_@hotmail.com`. Latex does not recognize the command `\ead{ufukkaya_@hotmail.com}`. Please help me.

Comment: `\_` ..........

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128514/586

Comment: You can also use `\usepackage{url}` and type `\url{ufukkaya_@hotmail.com}`

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{mailto: ufukkaya_@hotmail.com}{ufukkaya\_@hotmail.com}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There should'nt be a space between "mail" and "to", i.e., use `mailto: This_Should_Be_Obfuscated@hotmail.com` (BTW, the adress should be changed in the questions + comments. @StefanH, can you do that?)

Comment: (No need to obfuscate the address, actually: I just send an email to it and had a "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender".)